# Epson XP-225 does not print

Tags: printing, epson

I've just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my pc and i can't use the printer (Epson XP-225). I typed Printers in the dash, then found my printer and added it. So it started to look for drivers and installed them. Once it ended i was asked to print the test page, so i did but nothing happened. I tryed to print also other files but nothing; to delete them and retry but still no signs of improvement. What I noticed is that after i give the pc the input to print, the status of the printer becomes " Processing page 1" and stays still, in the meanwhile the power light starts blinking and doesnt stop till i turn the printer off. How can i fix? Thanks

Comment: Try to install drivers manually from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult You will need `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` file, if you have a 64-bit system.

Comment: Please install the drivers from the manufacturer, or there may be a DVD to install drivers for your printer. If there is, use that DVD.

Answer (score 1):

Did you search for your driver on www.openprinting.org I also have an epson but a different model and drivers work perfect

### Before install

Make sure to know if you are using a 32 or 64 bit OS to do that:

```
Hit Command(mac) or Window key.
Type Details, and select "Details" icon
Read "OS type" field
64 bit OS will read "64-bit"
```

[image]

### **Download**

**First option**:
[Search for your driver on the manufacturer web page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) 
Once there: Search for XP-225 DO NOT choose an operating system. There are three linux results: (1)first one is the driver, (2) second one is an utility wich you may want to downlaod as i understand your computer allows wifi printing and it might help you. (3) third is the scanner driver

**Second Option**
Once you know what OS you have go to https://www.openprinting.org/
 and search for your printer. 
**Make sure to download the proper 32 or 64 bit file and it should be a DEB file not RPM**

I save you the trouble to find your printer it is here: 
https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-XP-225_Series

**Install**
Once you download the DEB you should be able to install it just with a double click i recommend to use GDEBI

Comment: I downloaded and installed drivers (64 bit) manually as you told me and i didn't have any kind of trouble, but the problem isn't fixed. When i try to print the powerlight starts blinking and the printer doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you sure is not a physical problem with the printer?

Comment: Yes, before ubuntu i had win7 and it worked.. so i guess there are no physical issues

Comment: Ok i search for your driver on the manufacturer web page and i found it: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule  search for XP-225  DO NOT choose an operating system. There are two linux result first one is the driver second one is an utility wich you may want to downlaod as i understand your computer allows wifi printing and it might help you

Comment: There is also a third linux result which seems like a scanner driver i suppose your printer is an all-in-one so you probably want to download it as well,  it is not 4th but 5th result

Comment: Well i downloaded the first one and now it works perfectly! I really appreciated the help, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcomed ! Please mark my answer as solved so it gets stored :)